# Write to realm (successful), segue to NextVC (successful) and display string data from previous VC that was saved to realm (need help)

Tags: ios, swift, button, realm, segue

I have a bar button function called `saveTapped` on the `FirstVC`. When this is tapped I have a number of pieces of string data being written to a Realm Database successfully.

I am attempting to

1. Get the `saveTapped` button to save/write the data to realm (this is working)
2. Once the data is written to realm, to segue to the `NextVC` View Controller (this is working, with a segue with the identifier `saveTappedSegue` direct from the `FirstVC`)

to then

3. Display the information that has just been saved to the Realm Database in the `NextVC`.

I have the following code layout;

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "saveTappedSegue" {
            let dest = segue.destination as! NextVC

            dest.NextVCLabel1.text = UITextField1.text // Errors thrown here
            dest.NextVCLabel2.text = UITextField2.text etc.etc.

    }
}

@IBAction func saveTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let realm = try! Realm()

    var realmClassName = RealmClassToInheritFrom()
        realmClassName.classProperty1 = UITextField1.text
        realmClassName.classProperty2 = UITextField2.text
        realmClassName.classProperty3 = UITextField3.text etc. etc.

        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(realmClassName)
        }

       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveTappedSegue", sender: self)

    }
```

Error is `"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"`

I have step 1 and 2 working successfully.

I would like to have the information just saved into realm, to display on the `NextVC` in the following labels;

```
NextVCLabel1
NextVCLabel2
NextVCLabel3 etc etc.
```

I am currently looking at step three and removing the error to allow the UITextFields to display on the NextVC labels. I have read somewhere that I may need to time stamp, or give an `ID` to the data as it saves to make it easily accessible? I've only just figured out how to save to realm, so this is the first I've attempted to read data from realm to display.

Comment: I know there's a couple of answers but there's not info info here to answer completely. If you just want to display the info you just typed in, why not pass that info with a segue - realm doesn't need to be involved at all. How are you instantiating the second viewController? If you're doing it from the viewController that contains the UITextField inputs it would be even easier;  `secondViewController.label.text = UITextField1.text` right?

Comment: the secondVC is on storyboard with its own swift file with outlets for each Labels. 
the firstVC houses textFields for each data entry. 
I've attempted 
```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "saveTappedSegue" {
            let dest = segue.destination as! NextVC
                       
            dest.Label1.text = UITextField1.text //error
```
But my new error is "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" on the error line

Comment: Please don't put code in comments - it's very hard to read; add it to your question with formatting. Again, how are you spinning up the second view controller? Is it a child of the first, like Master->Detail scenario? If so then what I suggested is just the super simple solution. If you're getting an error with the existing code, we would need to see that code and also which line is throwing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways of doing this. You can perform all the logic inside prepareForSegue, or some inside saveTapped and some inside prepareForSegue. For example, first approach looks like this:

- Your saveTapped function has only one statement - performSegue.

```
    @objc func saveTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveTappedSegue", sender: self)
    }
```

- Inside NextVC, declare a variable per label and on viewDidLoad assign the value of each variable to its corresponding label:

```
    class NextVC: UIViewController {

        // Labels        
        @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

        // String variables
        var string1 = ""
        var string2 = ""

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Assign each string variable's content to its corresponding label
            label1.text = string1
            label2.text = string2
        }
     }
```

- Inside FirstVC, let's take care of the logic that needs to be implemented inside prepareForSegue:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "NEXTVC_SEGUE_ID" {            
            let destination = segue.destination as! NextViewController
            // Let's write to realm first
            let realm = try! Realm()

            var realmClassName = RealmClassToInheritFrom()
            realmClassName.classProperty1 = UITextField1.text
            realmClassName.classProperty2 = UITextField2.text
            realmClassName.classProperty3 = UITextField3.text etc. etc.

            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(realmClassName)
            }

            // Now let's set the NextVC's string variables
            destination.string1 = UITextField1.text
            destination.string2= UITextField2.text
        }
    }
```

Another approach would be to pass in the object instead.

Comment: thanks rs7. For `"NEXTVC_SEGUE_ID"` would I write `saveTappedSegue` or `"saveTappedSegue"`?. Or would I include something else as I get errors for the methods attempted.

Comment: You would replace that with "saveTappedSegue" which is the identifier of your segue. If you go to storyboard, select the segue and under attribute inspector, you should see an identifier field -- that's the one you want.

Comment: Thanks rs7. I've got that bit solved eventually. Next issue for me is 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value' in 'dest.NextVCLabel1.text = UITextField1.text'

Comment: Did you declare nextVCLabel1 inside your nextVC? If yes, make sure they are declared as nextVCLabel1 = UILabel() rather than nextVCLabel1 = UILabel? or UILabel!. If you declared them as optional, you have to initialize them inside prepareForSegue before assigning them a value.

Comment: On the NextVC currently each UILabel is: `@IBOutlet weak var nextVCLabel1 : UILabel!`
If I change to end with `()` and error on the same line is `@IBOutlet property has non-optional type 'UILabel'` and on the class line, `Class 'NextVC' has no initializers`.

Comment: If I change to `nextVCLabel1 = UILabel()` these errors appear: `weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'UILabel.Type'`
and

Comment: `IBOutlet property cannot have non-object type 'UILabel.Type'` 
and
`Replace '@IBOutlet ' with ''`
 and 
`Expected member name or constructor call after type name`
 and 
`Add arguments after the type to construct a value of the type`
and
`Use '.self' to reference the type object`

Comment: I got confused a bit confused here, my bad. I've updated my answer. Essentially, what you need to do is declare string variables (var text1 = "", var text2 = "" etc) inside your NextVC. Then, inside prepareForSegue, assign textField1.text to destination.text1, textField2.text to destination.text2 and so on. Finally, inside your NextVC's ViewDidLoad, then you can assign text1 to label1.text, text2 to label2.text and so on.

Comment: Basically, you can't directly assign a value to the label until the nextVC gets loaded and that explains the errors you were seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your help rs7. I've declared the string values under the `class NextVC: UIViewController { }` code as `var NextVCLabel1: String = ""` etc. I've commented out the `@IBOutlet weak var NextVCLabel1 : UILabel!`s. 
In my FirstVC inside prepareForSegue I have `dest.NextVCLabel1.text = UItextField1.text` etc. My new error next to each of these is `Value of type 'String' has no member 'text'` Would you recommend I remove the `let dest = segue.destination as! NextVC` at the start of the preareForSegue?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please read carefully. Also, just a side note, in Swift requires your variable names start with a lower case letter.

Comment: You sir are a hero. I re-read through and found errors I had made. I also had to force unwrap the `destination.string = textfield1.text!` to make it work. Thank you for your in depth help.

Answer (score 0):

You could query the database againfrom the next VC, but given you already have the data that would be overkill.

Use the `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method to inject the data from the current viewcontroller into the next.

There are numerous tutorials for Swift dependency injection if you have a quick google.